# Spring/Mockito Junit testing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

Trying to get JUnit with mockito testing to work and getting a NPE on my test here. I'm wanting to have a verify that when `createRegistrant(registrationDTO)` is called, `saveUpdateRegistration(Registration reg)` method is called right after. An issue I find strange is that on `Mockito.verify(registrationServiceImpl, Mockito.times(1)).createRegistrant(registrationDTO);` it is not suggesting I can test if `saveUpdateRegistration(Registration reg)` method was called? IntelliJ only suggests methods that are in my interface?

My test code below:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RegistrationServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private RegistrationServiceImpl registrationServiceImpl;

    @Mock
    private RegistrationDTO registrationDTO;

    @Mock
    private Registration registration;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        registrationDTO.seteId("abc123");
        registrationDTO.setTech("AWS");
        registrationDTO.setFirstName("Bob");
        registrationDTO.setLastName("Tom");

    }


    @Test
    public void createRegistrant() throws Exception {
//        Mockito.when(registrationServiceImpl.createRegistrant(registrationDTO)).thenReturn(registrationDTO);
        Mockito.when(registrationServiceImpl.createRegistrant(registrationDTO)).thenReturn(registrationDTO);
        registrationServiceImpl.createRegistrant(registrationDTO);
        Mockito.verify(registrationServiceImpl, Mockito.times(1)).createRegistrant(registrationDTO);
    }
```

Here is the code I'm testing:

```
package com.TechODex.service;

import com.TechODex.dto.RegistrationDTO;
import com.TechODex.model.Registration;
import com.TechODex.dao.RegistrationDAO;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class RegistrationServiceImpl implements RegistrationService {

    @Autowired
    private RegistrationDAO registrationDAO;

    public RegistrationDTO createRegistrant(RegistrationDTO reg) {
        saveUpdateRegistration(setDTOToModel(reg));
        return reg;
    }
    public void deleteRegistrant(Long id) { deleteUserRegistrant(id); }
    public List<Registration> findAllRegistrant(String tech) { return findAllRegistrantDAO(tech);}
    public List<Registration> findAllTech() { return findAllTechDAO();}


    private Registration setDTOToModel(RegistrationDTO dto){
        Registration registration = new Registration();

        registration.setFirstName(dto.getFirstName());
        registration.setLastName(dto.getLastName());
        registration.seteId(dto.geteId());
        registration.setTech(dto.getTech());

        return registration;
    }

    private void saveUpdateRegistration(Registration reg){ registrationDAO.save(reg);}

}
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the NPE? Is it `registrationDAO.save(reg)`? Because I can't see you mocking the `RegistrationDAO` which you are injecting into your `RegistrationServiceImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

First, you do not mock `RegistrationDAO`. This will lead to it being `null` in the class under test. Next, `RegistrationService` is not a mock, yet you try to use `when` and `verify`on it. Last, `RegistrationDTO` is mocked, so the invocations to the setters in `@Before` has no effect.

Your test should look something like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RegistrationServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private RegistrationServiceImpl registrationServiceImpl;

    @Mock
    private RegistrationDAO registrationDAO;

    private RegistrationDTO registrationDTO;
    private Registration registration;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        registration = new Registration();
        registration.seteId("abc123");
        registration.setTech("AWS");
        registration.setFirstName("Bob");
        registration.setLastName("Tom");

        registrationDTO = new RegistrationDTO();
        registrationDTO.seteId("abc123");
        registrationDTO.setTech("AWS");
        registrationDTO.setFirstName("Bob");
        registrationDTO.setLastName("Tom");
    }

    @Test
    public void createRegistrant() throws Exception {
        final RegistrationDTO result = registrationServiceImpl.createRegistrant(registrationDTO);
        assertSame(registrationDTO, result);        

        verify(registrationDAO).save(eq(registration));
    }
}
```

given that `Registration` has an implemented equals-method where the fields that are set are compared. If not, you need to use an `ArgumentCaptor`.

Comment: oooohhh I see, I need to mock the DAO because it is Autowired into my service class in the normal impl. And the @Before is just setting up the data to be used with in the impl test class. That makes perfect sense!! Thanks Tobb!

Comment: I do have a quick question. I had to add `refEq` to get it to work? What exactly does that do?

Comment: The `eq` method? It is statically imported from Mockito, and it is a `matcher`, using the equals method. Basically states "verify that the save method of registrationDAO has been invoked, with a parameter equal to registration".